# Stacking multiple tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am essentially trying to do a UNION all on multiple tables and have the result be a new table. I know that I can do this to select and stack all of the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
....
```

But how do I make that into its own table?

Thanks!

Comment: Put `into` in the first `select`:  `select * into newtable from table1 . . . `.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
SELECT * INTO [new_tablename] FROM table1

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSI version:

`create table supremeTable ( oneOfYourManyGreatColumns int, ... );`

```
insert into supremeTable
    select * from table1
    union all
    select * from table2...;
```

or even

```
merge into supremeTable as _d
using (
    select * from table 1
    union all...
) as _s
on 0 = 1
when not matched then
    insert (
        thisAllowsYouTo,
        changeTheColumnMappings
    )
    values (
        _s.fromTheSourceTables,
        _s.toTheDestination
    ); -- don't forget that ANSI semicolon!
```